# Как получить путь к файлу который лежит в папке ресурсов raw? `

Tags: java, android

У меня в папке ресурсов лежит файл. Как можно получитьь его путь, для того, чтоб прочитать?

Вот функция которая читает файл

```
public String readTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) {
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

но как мне пердать ему путь к файлу(resId) если его имя не известно?

Я могу получить массив всех элементов которые там находятся вот так

```
Field[] raw = R.raw.class.getFields();
```

Но как получить из него путь к файлу чтоб передать его в функцию которую я описал выше для прочтения? Допустим мне нужен путь к первому файлу в этом массиве...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему вот этот [код](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12275199/3212712) для drawable папки должен вам помочь, если заменить на raw:

```
Field[] ID_Fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
int[] resArray = new int[ID_Fields.length];
for(int i = 0; i < ID_Fields.length; i++) {
    try {
        resArray[i] = ID_Fields[i].getInt(null);
        System.out.println(resArray[i]);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```